# Why is python itertools "consume" recipe faster than calling next n times?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

In the python documentation for itertools it provides the following "recipe" for advancing an iterator n steps:

```
def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

I'm wondering why this recipe is fundamentally different from something like this (aside from the handling of consuming the whole iterator):

```
def other_consume(iterable, n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        next(iterable, None)
```

I used `timeit` to confirm that, as expected, the above approach is much slower. What's going on in the recipe that allows for this superior performance? I get that it uses `islice`, but looking at `islice`, it APPEARS to be doing fundamentally the same thing as the code above:

```
def islice(iterable, *args):
    s = slice(*args)
    it = iter(xrange(s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxint, s.step or 1))
    nexti = next(it)
    ### it seems as if this loop yields from the iterable n times via enumerate
    ### how is this different from calling next n times?
    for i, element in enumerate(iterable): 
        if i == nexti:
            yield element
            nexti = next(it)
```

Note: even if instead of importing `islice` from `itertools` I define it using the python equivalent from the docs shown above, the recipe is still faster..

EDIT: `timeit` code here:

```
timeit.timeit('a = iter([random() for i in xrange(1000000)]); consume(a, 1000000)', setup="from __main__ import consume,random", number=10)
timeit.timeit('a = iter([random() for i in xrange(1000000)]); other_consume(a, 1000000)', setup="from __main__ import other_consume,random", number=10)
```

`other_consume` is ~ 2.5x slower each time I run this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on `itertools.islice()` is flawed and doesn't handle the edgecase for `start == stop` properly. It is exactly that edgecase that `consume()` uses.

For `islice(it, n, n)`, exactly `n` elements are consumed from `it` but nothing is ever yielded. Instead, `StopIteration` is raised after those `n` elements have been consumed.

The Python version you used to test with on the other hand *raises `StopIteration` immediately* without ever consuming *anything* from `it`. This makes any timings against this pure-python version incorrect and way too fast.

This is because the `xrange(n, n, 1)` iterator immediately raises `StopIteration`:

```
>>> it = iter(xrange(1, 1))
>>> print next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 4, in <module>
    print next(it)
StopIteration
```

Comment: I think this only explains a modest amount of the speed difference. Using the naive version takes about 10 times as much as the `itertools.islice` the recipe. Replacing the `for i in range(n)` with an enumerate loop (breaking when the index equals `n`) reduces the time take to 7 times as long as the itertools version, but I think the rest from having logic entirely in C.

Comment: Indeed, it's the flaw in the docs that makes the OP test flawed.

Comment: Indeed as implemented my consume never consumes anything!

Comment: And apologies for the slower answer speed; testing and typing all this on an iPhone is *slow*.

Answer (score 6):

The reason that the recipe is faster is that its key pieces (`islice`, `deque`) are implemented in C, rather than in pure Python. Part of it is that a C loop is faster than `for i in xrange(n)`. Another part is that Python function calls (e.g. `next()`) are more expensive than their C equivalents.

The version of `itertools.islice` that you've copied from the documentation is not correct, and its apparently great performance is because a consume function using it doesn't consume anything. (For that reason I'm not showing that version's test results below, though it was pretty fast! :)

Here are a couple different implementations, so we can test what is fastest:

```
import collections
from itertools import islice

# this is the official recipe
def consume_itertools(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)

# your initial version, using a for loop on a range
def consume_qwwqwwq(iterator, n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        next(iterator, None)

# a slightly better version, that only has a single loop:
def consume_blckknght(iterator, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    for i, v in enumerate(iterator, start=1):
        if i == n:
            break
```

Timings on my system (Python 2.7.3 64-bit on Windows 7):

```
>>> test = 'consume(iter(xrange(100000)), 1000)'
>>> timeit.timeit(test, 'from consume import consume_itertools as consume')
7.623556181657534
>>> timeit.timeit(test, 'from consume import consume_qwwqwwq as consume')
106.8907442334584
>>> timeit.timeit(test, 'from consume import consume_blckknght as consume')
56.81081856366518
```

My assessment is that a nearly empty Python loop takes seven or eight times longer to run than the equivalent loop in C. Looping over two sequences at once (as `consume_qwwqwwq` does by calling next on `iterator` in addition to the `for` loop on the `xrange`) makes the cost roughly double.

Comment: I am implementing islice in pure python and still getting the same results as I explain in my question, so this cant be the reason

Comment: @qwwqwwq How are you timing it? I imagine you are either using a tiny amount of data, so the time it takes to do it really doesn't matter, and overhead happens to be higher, or you are getting the timing wrong.

Comment: @qwwqwwq: Your pure Python `islice` implementation doesn't work correctly. It does nothing when `start` and `stop` are both the same (`next(iter(xrange(100, 100)))` raises `StopIteration` immediately). Since that's what the `consume` function calls it with, your consume will not consume anything (but it will do so very quickly!).

Comment: ah I see.. I copied that code for islice straight from the docs, guess it was incorrect..? if you put in an answer I will accept

Comment: @qwwqwwq: I've updated with several different implementations that I've timed against each other. A pure Python version using `enumerate` to loop over the iterator directly takes about 7.5 times longer than the `itertools` recipe. The simple code you posed as an example takes almost twice as long (14 times as long as the `itertools` code in my test). So, I thin the doubled `next` calls that @MartijnPieters mentioned in his answer are responsible for about half the slowdown you were seeing. The rest of the story is that any Python loop is going to be slower than the equivalent in C.